# What exactly is ListSelectionModel.insertIndexInterval() doing?

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to write my own implementation of [ListSelectionModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/ListSelectionModel.html) and currently I'm stuck while trying to implement `insertIndexInterval`. I don't understand the result of this method in Sun's/Oracle's `DefautListSelectionModel` implementation. Here is an example:

```
ListSelectionModel model = new DefaultListSelectionModel();
model.setSelectionInterval(3, 5);
model.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener()
{
    public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e)
    {
        System.out.println("Changed range reported by event: " +
            e.getFirstIndex() + "-" + e.getLastIndex());
    }
});

System.out.print("Selected indices before insert: ");
for (int i = model.getMinSelectionIndex(); i <= model.getMaxSelectionIndex(); i++)
    if (model.isSelectedIndex(i)) System.out.print(i + " ");
System.out.println();

model.insertIndexInterval(3, 3, true);  

System.out.print("Selected indices after insert: ");
for (int i = model.getMinSelectionIndex(); i <= model.getMaxSelectionIndex(); i++)
    if (model.isSelectedIndex(i)) System.out.print(i + " ");
System.out.println();
```

When you run this code you will get this output:

```
Selected indices before insert: 3 4 5 
Changed range reported by event: 3-8
Selected indices after insert: 3 4 5 6 7 8
```

So the initial selection was 3-5 and it was expanded to 3-8 when inserting new indices. But 3-5 were already selected so the real change is only 6-8 so why is the event telling me that the range 3-8 has been changed? It is even more confusing when you change the `insertIndexInterval` call to this:

```
model.insertIndexInterval(3, 3, false);
```

Now the output is this:

```
Selected indices before insert: 3 4 5 
Changed range reported by event: 5-8
Selected indices after insert: 3 4 5 6 7 8
```

I have no idea why the reported change is 5-8.

The API documentation of this method is much too short to understand what is going on there. Especially this `before` parameter is a mystery to me because it never has any effect on the selection but it seems to have some effect on the event and on the lead and anchor indexes.

I can't even write a unit test for my implementation because I simply don't know the expected results.

So can someone explain in detail what this method (And especially the `before`flag) is doing and what side effects it has on the selection model and the `ListSelectionEvent`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is used when new data is added to the data model (so the current selection indexes should be moved). If 2 means 'newly added and selected' than your output would be:

```
[0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0] == [3A,4,5L]
-> add after [0,0,0,1,2,2,2,1,1,0] == [3A,4,5,6,7,8L]
-> add before [0,0,0,2,2,2,1,1,1,0] == [3,4,5,6A,7,8L]
```

What you see here is a feature* of DefaultListSelectionModel - adding indices inside a current selection, automatically expands the selection.

Start with for example with index 1 selected, then insert three rows at index three:

```
[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
-> add after [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
```

Note that your selection representation is misleading, the zeros aren't really there. A better way to print the selection state would be:

```
private static void printSelection(ListSelectionModel model) {
    System.out.print("[");
    for (int i = model.getMinSelectionIndex(); i <= model.getMaxSelectionIndex(); i++) {
        if(i > model.getMinSelectionIndex()) {
            System.out.print(",");
        }
        if(model.isSelectedIndex(i)) {
            System.out.print(i);
            if(i == model.getAnchorSelectionIndex()) {
                System.out.print("A");
            }
            if(i == model.getLeadSelectionIndex()) {
                System.out.print("L");
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println("]");
}
```

*) The documentation of DefaultListSelectionModel#insertIndexInterval differs from the interface, see also https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4700643 and http://java.net/jira/browse/SWINGX-272

Comment: Yes, I know the zeros are not really there. It is just easier to compare in that way. But I still don't get it. The event is bound to the selection model, not the data model. Indices 3-5 were already selected before inserting new data so the only real change (to the selection model, not the data model) is the additional selection range of 6-8. But the reported change is 3-8 (When before=true) and 5-8 (When before=false). Especially this 5-8 makes no sense so far.

Comment: Yes, then it explains the 3-8 (Because the 1s has been moved and the 2s has been added) but how do you explain the 5-8 range reported when using before=false? When visualizing it as three-state then it has to be 6-8 because the three 1s doesn't move and the three 2s are inserted at index 6, not 5.

Comment: BTW: When inserting after index 3 then it should be 0001222110 and not 0001112220, or not?. Documentation says "Insert length indices beginning before/after index".

Comment: @kayahr Imagine you list has 6 items to start and 3, 4, 5 is selected. In you insert 3 rows before row 3, that selection moves up to 6, 7, 8. The reason you see these event ranges (I guess you expected 6-8 in the after insert) is because the lead selection index changes from 5 to 8 which means the focus should be painted on row 8 now instead of 5. Oddly enough the anchor changes from 3 to 6 in before, so you get the 3-8 range.

Comment: @kayahr ahh ... good catch, hadn't noticed the 5 vs 6, that's why I had been wondering why you were surprised :-)

Comment: hmm ... removed my three-state comment (only makes sense for the before but not the afte insert, just a @kayahr pointed out)

Comment: NOW I get it. So the change range reported by the event doesn't only contain the changes of the selection state but also the changes of the lead and anchor indexes. Yes, that makes sense now. Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

EDIT I hope that we talking about JList, not about JTable, then rest is in the notice

can you please use this [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) and edit your question with code clearly domostrating your issues with `ListSelectionModel`, `ListeSelectionMode` and related code's workaround, `notice` this `Listener` have got only one `dimension` or `directional`,

```
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.event.InputEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Ctrl_Down_JList {

    private static void createAndShowUI() {
        String[] items = {"Sun", "Mon", "Tues", "Wed", "Thurs", "Fri", "Sat"};
        JList myJList = new JList(items) {

            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            protected void processMouseEvent(MouseEvent e) {
                int modifiers = e.getModifiers() | InputEvent.CTRL_MASK;
                // change the modifiers to believe that control key is down
                int modifiersEx = e.getModifiersEx() | InputEvent.CTRL_MASK;
                // can I use this anywhere?  I don't see how to change the modifiersEx of the MouseEvent
                MouseEvent myME = new MouseEvent((Component) e.getSource(), e.getID(), e.getWhen(), modifiers, e.getX(),
                        e.getY(), e.getXOnScreen(), e.getYOnScreen(), e.getClickCount(), e.isPopupTrigger(), e.getButton());
                super.processMouseEvent(myME);
            }
        };
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Ctrl_Down_JList");
        frame.getContentPane().add(new JScrollPane(myJList));
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                createAndShowUI();
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: @Walter Laan you are right, but why bothering without knows SelectionMode, then things could be simpler as you describe in your answer +1 for bothering, EDIT and rest you'll see in the comment in your answer :-)

Comment: I've added a full code example. I hope it demonstrates my problem good enough.